# How to get image data with DJI OSDK using DJI matrice 600 pro

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm trying to do some image-processing using matrice 600pro(drone) with a jetson Xavier(mini computer) attached.  
A camera which has HDMI output function is attached to ronin-MX(gimbal) and data will be transmitted through SRW-60G(wireless video link using hdmi port).  
I thought using some functions in onboard sdk such like "/dji_sdk/main_camera_images (sensor_msgs/Image)"
(http://wiki.ros.org/dji_sdk)
can get image data easily,  
but I found that those functions are only available for M210 so I may cannot use these on my matrice 600pro. 
Using a HDMI-USB converter may could solve this problem(make the camera-transmitter-receiver as a usb camera)  
but the converter is quite expensive and I'm not sure if there's better way to do this.  
Any clue will be very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as i know, osdk does not support video streaming for M600 series. The thing you can do is to use Ronnin gimbal with a 3rd party camera e.g ids/flir/matrixvision camera to direct connect to xavier. then based on this stream, do your processing.

If you need to stream the 3rd party video source down, its easier. Just use opencv imshow in full screen for current frame. This will output to desktop hdmi. Connect HDMI to the m600 video port. it will be stream down to your remote controller.  THis is like a cheap version of the PSDK

Hope this will help you with your development work

Regards
Dr Yuan Shenghai

Comment: Thank you for reply. I attached a capture card to the video link receiver to get my camera video stream wireless. I think OSDK can not do video steaming on M600 is probably because lightbridge2 is separate to main controller compare to M200 series.

Comment: thats one way.  The M200 series has better internal image pipeline. You can grab the UDP stream at the port behind. But it is not very stable. at 3.8 0% running chance.  at 3.9 only 40% success rate.    So far using LB2 or 5G to stream down my PC output  is my current configuration.